# Two distinct vectors $x,y$, and existence of linear functional.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be vector space, and let $x,y\in V$, s.t $x\neq y$. Then exist linear functional, $\phi$, s.t $\phi(x)\neq\phi(y)$

How do I prove the *exist* part?

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints:

1) If $\,\{x,y\}\,$ linearly independent, then complete this set to a basis of $\,V\,$ and define

$$\phi(v):=\begin{cases}1&,\;\; v=x\\0&,\;\;v\neq x\end{cases}$$

and extend definition by linearity

2) If $\,y=kx\,\,\,,\,\,k\in\Bbb F=\,$definition field, then $\,k\neq 1\,$ ,and completing $\,\{x\}\,$ to a basis of $\,V\,$ (why $\,x\neq 0\,$?) , define$\,\phi\,$ as above , and $\,\phi(y)=k\phi(x)\neq\phi(x)\,$

Answer (score 0):

Choose a Hamel basis $\mathcal{B}$ and write $x-y = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i b_i$ where $\alpha_i$ are in the scalar field and $b_i \in \mathcal{B}$. Then some $\alpha_j \neq 0$ since $x-y \neq 0$.
Then $T_j$ the projection mapping onto the $b_j$ vector has $T_j(x-y) = \alpha_j \neq 0$, hence $T_j(x) \neq T_j(y)$.

Answer (score 0):

By linearity, it is enough to do that for $y=0$. Then $x\neq 0$. So complete $\{x\}$ into a basis of $V$. Set $\phi(\lambda x):=\lambda$. Then extend by what you want on the remainder of the basis. Say by $0$.